# javascript different backgrounds on tap

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a list to create a "select top 3", and I am using a javascript to collect the selections and list them. However, I would like to change the background of each selection, depending on when they are selected.

1st selection -> Green background
2nd selection -> Yellow background
3rd selection -> Red background

JavaScript:

```
events: {
    'tap #achieveList li': "makeSelection"
  },

  makeSelection: function(e) {
    var radioBtn = e.target;
    var selected = this.el.getElementsByClassName('selected');

    if (radioBtn) {
      if (radioBtn.classList.contains('selected')) {
        radioBtn.classList.remove('selected');
      } else if (selected.length < 3) {
        radioBtn.classList.add('selected');
      }
      this.monitorSelections(selected);
    }
  },
  monitorSelections: function(selected) {
    if (!selected) return;

    var selection = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
      selection.push(selected[i].innerHTML);
    };

    ag.submit.data({
      label: "This is top 3",
      category: "User input",
      value: selection.join(','),
      valueType: "list",
      path: app.getPath(),
      unique: true
    });

  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="interactive-block">
  <ul id="achieveList">
    <li>More engagements</li>
    <li>Cost efficiencies</li>
    <li>Better access</li>
    <li>Higher customer value/satisfaction</li>
    <li>Become more digital</li>
    <li>Better customer insights</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What library do you use to handle the tap event that way e.g. jQuery mobile etc. It does not look like vanilla JS.

Comment: I use Touchy.js http://jofan.github.io/Touchy/

Answer (score 2):

A) If I understood you well, you don't need a library for that:

```
let arr = []

const $$li = document.querySelectorAll('li')
$$li.forEach($li => $li.onclick = () => {
  // Remove classes
  $$li.forEach($li => $li.className = '')
  // Add clicked if not included
  if (!arr.includes($li)) arr.unshift($li)
  // No more than 3
  if (arr.length > 3) arr.pop()
  // Set classes
  arr.forEach(($li, i) => $li.classList.add(`bg${i + 1}`))
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/my2tw36d/

Play with the example linked above clicking/tapping your list items to check if this is what you're looking for.

B) After reading your comment you can achieve that easily changing 2 words from my previous example. With the reversed array we don't need to change how we set our CSS classes.

```
// Add selection if not included
if (!arr.includes($li)) arr.push($li)
// No more than 3
if (arr.length > 3) arr.shift()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/unatfyo5/

C) If you want to block after 3 selections then you need this:

```
if (!arr.includes($li) && arr.length < 3) arr.unshift($li)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stLghxor/

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is in the right direction. However, the elements change color, when you select a new element. I would like the first element to stay green, when you select the next two.